# Using Variable in Update Case Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I am using a CASE statement as part of an Update procedure, and in the past I simply repeated the test query on each line of the case statement, as below, and this works successfully.

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_name = 
CASE
    WHEN TRIM(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(line, ' ',2), LOCATE(' ',line))) = 'Jan' THEN 01
    WHEN TRIM(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(line, ' ',2), LOCATE(' ',line))) = 'Feb' THEN 02    
    WHEN TRIM(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(line, ' ',2), LOCATE(' ',line))) = 'Mar' THEN 03
    etc...
END
WHERE column_name IS NULL
```

I want to avoid the CASE statement having to process the test query after each time it doesn't get a match on a condition. The tables I am running this procedures against can be  quite large so I am aiming for a little processing efficiency.

I thought of running the test query once per row, and saving the result into a variable. The CASE statement then checks that variable and acts accordingly when it gets a match.

When I run the query below, I get an error message,

> Error in query (1064): Syntax error near 'UPDATE table_name SET logMonth = CASE WHEN @var_col' at line 3

```
SET @var_column_name = TRIM(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(line, ' ',2), LOCATE(' ',line)))

UPDATE table_name
SET column_name = 
CASE
    WHEN @var_column_name = 'Jan' THEN 01
    WHEN @var_column_name = 'Feb' THEN 02    
    WHEN @var_column_name = 'Mar' THEN 03
    etc ...
END
WHERE column_name IS NULL
```

Comment: Every statement must be terminated - neither of yours are. Also where do field and line come from - are these parameters passed to the procedure?

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS Mothify;
DELIMITER ;;

CREATE PROCEDURE Mothify()
BEGIN
  DECLARE tmp_id INT;
  DECLARE tmp_val VARCHAR(200);
  DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR SELECT id, TRIM(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(field, ' ',2), LOCATE(' ',line))) FROM tb where col is null;

  OPEN curs;
  row_looping: LOOP
    FETCH curs INTO tmp_id, tmp_val;

    UPDATE tb
    SET col = 
    CASE
      WHEN tmp_val = 'Jan' THEN 01
      WHEN tmp_val = 'Feb' THEN 02    
      WHEN tmp_val = 'Mar' THEN 03
      #etc..
    END
    WHERE  id = tmp_id;    

  END LOOP;
  CLOSE curs;
END;
;;
```

Comment: That doesnt work: Error in query (1054): Unknown column 'line' in 'field list'.

Comment: read the edit. you can execute this to create your procedure to call every time you need to calculate. Just replace the aliases tb, col and id.  Then when you'll need just excute : CALL Monthify();

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a primary key, you can define the value in a subquery and use:

```
UPDATE table_name t JOIN
       (SELECT tt.*,
               TRIM(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(line, ' ',2), LOCATE(' ',line))) as x
        FROM table_name tt
       ) tt
       ON tt.<primary key> = t.<primary key>
    SET t.column_name = (CASE WHEN tt.x = 'JAN' THEN 01
                              WHEN tt.x = 'FEB' THEN 02
                              . . .
                          END)
    WHERE column_name IS NULL;
```